# Failed to start File System Check on

Tags: boot, startup, fstab

A couple hours ago tried to start my Ubuntu laptop after a few months without using it and I found myself with this:

[image: When I boot Ubuntu I get up to this screen][image]

I'm far from understanding what's exactly happening here. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: type `journalctl -xb` and see what it has to say!

Comment: Added a screenshot of the part where it mentions the same error. Does it help?

Comment: run this command `fsck /dev/sda2` and accept all options

Comment: Is it back up ?

Comment: It's working! yes!

Comment: Make sure you do an update on your system to bring it up to speed with the latest updates! Cheers!

Comment: @wjandrea I have done so!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess for your situation would be that environmental changes have affected you HDD. So from the error message from `journalctl -xb` which points to file inconsistencies and the instruction to run manual file check. Use the `fsck` command to correct this error:

```
fsck /dev/sda2
```

And simply accept all the options give during the process. Then reboot you system.

Comment: How to find out which sda or sdb is it in my case?

Comment: I think the error message should tell you which it is! @sashkolykhenko

Comment: Well I never found it in the message, I brute-forced through all drives instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer before https://askubuntu.com/a/1095536/676490

In my case helped:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
sudo fsck /dev/sda2
sudo fsck /dev/sda3
sudo fsck /dev/sda4
```

And I accepted everthing with y (yes)

If you want to accept all automatically you can use ihmo the `-y`-flag:

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda4
```

or simmilar